# In jQueryUI sortable widget, how can you perform a cancel operation in the start method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

jQueryUI sortable widget throws an exception (this.helper is null) when you try to perform a cancel operation in the start method. Here is an illustration:

```
$('#sort').sortable({
    start: function() {        
        $(this).sortable('cancel'); //cancel operation. Causes an exception (this.helper = null)
    }
});
```

See this jsfiddle for live code-example

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ke8q/1/

Is there any workaround to have the cancel option used in the start menu in jQueryUI sortable widget?

Comment: Why you want to cancel it in the start function? Can't you use stop or receive? Can you elaborate why?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I excluded the actual code I am using that sheds full light on your question, to keep the issue focused. I do not want reordering to take place (it would if I add cancel to the stop or recieve methods) if it should not. Otherwise, my use of Knockout.js gets out of sync. That is why I need the cancel to be in start (prevents reordering from occuring) or if possible earlier. Did that answer your question?

Comment: You want to revert it at runtime or some sortable must be always not sortable?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward some items must not be sortable. Unfortunely, selecting items to include has an issue where excluded items can be selected and used to move the entire parent-UL (as opposed to just the LI). This may be due to the exclude item being children of a included. Anyway, It is weird and unaccepatble. That is why I am trying to prevent move in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that if you read the jQuery UI documentation, the cancel operation is supported only on the stop and receive events. Basically, once a user starts dragging, you cannot revert that until after an item is dropped in a new location.